# One-shot POST file upload policies for S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know it's possible to create a pre-signed policy allowing a user to upload a file to a specific key prefix with an expiration time, but the issue is that the same pre-signed policy can be used many times to upload as many files into the bucket while the policy hasn't expired.

For example, if we have a key prefix `a/b/` enforced via a policy with the actual key being `a/b/${filename}`, a user may reuse the policy many times to upload a file to that key prefix.

Is there any way of making a policy a one shot policy where after a successful upload, the policy becomes invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quite hard to do, but technically it is possible to do with a bit of a hacky solution, if you don't mind jumping through a few hoops, and custom coding your Url presign step, as well as a Lambda function!

The way presigned URLs work is that they are signed by the AccessKey and SecretKey of the identity who generates them.  The signature is time limited and operation limited and included in the URL along with the AccessKey and Expiry time.  The signature is verified using Amazon's knowledge of the AccessKey to ensures that it matches the operation and hasn't expired.

So there is no record stored in amazon about the existence of the pre-signed URL - it doesn't need one - all the info to validate the URL is contained in the signature and the AccessKey/SecretKey pair.

Since there is no record in amazon about the pre-signed Url, there is nothing you can do to disable it or remove it... except for the access key itself.  If you delete or disable the access key used to pre-sign the Url, then the Url will stop working.

This is where it gets tricky, because if you are using the access key to sign the Url, then you probably want to keep using the Access Key.  But if you don't mind rotating keys on every single pre-signed Url, then there is a mechanism that will work, using S3 Events and Lambda.

Here we go...

### Generating the Pre-Signed Url

To generate a pre-signed Url that can be disabled, do the following every time you want to generate a Url:

1. Add a new access key/secret key to your account - see [CreateAccessKey API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAccessKey.html)
2. Store your new access key, as you're going to have to use it for the next request
3. Obtain some unique information about the url to be signed - should be unique per pre-signed Url.  Possible the Key prefix?  If the key prefix is not unique, this solution will be a bit trickier...
4. Add a record to a database (e.g. DyanmoDb) that will be accessible to your Lambda function, which maps that data as the key, to the current AccessKeyId as the value.
5. Use your current access key to sign a Url
6. Distribute the pre-signed Url
7. Rotate your configuration to use the new access key on the next request

### Lambda function

Create a lambda function that will be triggered by every s3:ObjectCreated:* event.

In the lambda function, you will receive the event records as the method argument. Each event has a number of fields about the bucket and key.  Find the information that you used as the key when storing the AccessKeyId.

The lambda function should look up the database record to obtain the AccessKey associated with that information.

### Disabling the Access Key

Once you have the AWSAccessKey your lambda function can use the [DeleteAccessKey](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteAccessKey.html) API call to delete the access key.

The pre-signed Url will no longer work.

You may also want to delete the record from the database, just to clean house.

### Configuring S3 To Trigger Lambda on the Event

In s3 console, go into the bucket, then into the Events area, you can choose Lambda as the notification type and put in the arn of the lambda function.

### Conclusion

As you can see - it's not easy, but as far as I can tell this is the only way that will work.  If there's an easier way, I've completely missed it, but would love to know!

### A note about Instance Roles

The above solution isn't guaranteed if you are using Iam Instance Roles on an EC2 instance to presign the Url.  I'd have to do more research into the implications there, so suggest if you do adopt the above technique, ensure you are using a regular Iam Role (which unfortunately is against best practice recommendations when running software on an Ec2 Instance).

### Further Reading

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html for more info on using lambda with s3.  The second example was the inspiration for this method.